# How to change error styles in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to highlight the error in more aggressive way, is it possible in VS Code?

Basically to change style of this:

[image]

UPD: example of aggressive highlight in webStorm:

[image]

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to change the appearance of errors. What exactly do you mean with "more aggressive"?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE** - Nov 2020

Properties to set a background color on error styles are finally coming! [Merged PR here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110112)

```
editorInfo.background
editorWarning.background
editorError.background
```

**This is not shipped yet** - I suppose it will likely ship in the next major version (**v1.16**). Will update here to confirm the version when this happens.

---

**v1.12 and above**

Customization of error underline colors are now available natively via `workbench.colorCustomizations` in workspace settings. [See the docs here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference).

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorError.foreground": "#000000", // squiggly line
  "editorError.border": "#ffffff" // additional border under squiggly line
}
```

*Unfortunately, as far as I can find, for now the native customizations are  limited to this. To highlight the error with a background color, for example, you will still have to resort to the plugin method below...*

---

**v1.7.2 and above**

Error styles can be fully customised via css with the [vscode-custom-css](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension.

Create a file `custom-styles.css` with the following (change the styles as preferred)

```
.monaco-editor.vs .redsquiggly,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .redsquiggly {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Point the extension to `custom-styles.css` by adding the following in `Preferences > User Settings` (`settings.json`)

```
{
  "vscode_custom_css.imports" : [
    "file:///path/to/file/custom-styles.css"
  ]
}
```

Open up the command palette (Mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, Windows/Linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and search for and execute `Enable Custom CSS and JS`, then restart VS Code.

**You're done!**

Screenshot with the above styles applied: [image: Screenshot with the above styles applied]

*If you get any mistakes in the config, or you make any changes in `custom-styles.css`, try restarting VS Code completely, and it should refresh and pick up the correctly configured/new styles.*

---

**N.B.** Thanks @Stepan Suvorov for raising the github issue and @Matt Bierner for pointing out the appropriate css, so I could get this fixed with the extension.

If any VS Code devs happen to be reading this, firstly thanks - VS Code is awesome - but the built-in error styling is a significant accessibility issue for colourblind people. I'm red-green colourblind and the red squiggle on a black background is quite a strain to notice for me, particularly with single characters.

The ability to customise the error styles is last thing I really missed, switching to VS Code from atom. Official support for this would be a great feature!

Answer (score 3):

After almost a year, unfortunately, vscode-custom-css stop working for me; in the meantime vscode introduced some settings to customize the layout.

Try to add this in the user settings:

```
{
  // ...,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.border": "#ca2323a4",
    "editorError.foreground": "#ffffffb7"
  }
}
```

It will show the errors in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will soon be able to modify the background color of errors, warnings and info.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110112, should be in v1.52.

```
editorError.background
editorWarning.background
editorInfo.background
```

Previously, the background color could not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This works in version 1.58.0:

The following JSON goes into your settings.json, which I accessed via settings -> Workbench -> Appearance -> Color Customization:

```
{
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "errorForeground": "#ffffff",
        "editorError.background": "#ff0000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#ffffff",
        "editorWarning.background": "#dddd00",
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#ffffff",
        "editorInfo.background": "#0000ff"

    }
}
```

Comment: This was the one I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, changing the styling of errors is not something that VSCode themes or extensions can currently do. This logic is built in. Here's the [css used to render the `redsquiggly` currently](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/2f76c44632b0d47ba97f66fbc158c763628e30b3/src/vs/editor/browser/widget/media/editor.css#L125)

I suggest you [open a feature request against VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)