# Change error highlight color in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I build a project and get some problems in the "Problems view", I click on the problem to see a line of code with that problem highlighted.

And it gets highlighted indeed. However, if dark-styled theme is used, highlight is, for me at least, really hard to notice (line 23 is highlighted):

[image]

I guess this color can't be simply hard-coded somewhere since it's different in, for example, red theme and light-styled themes:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to change this color?

UPD: This question is not a duplicate of ["change the error style"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697223/how-to-change-error-styles-in-vs-code); error style (squiggle) applies to all errors at once, my question is about highlighting only the selected error.

Comment: @Alex yes. Sorry if my way of saying it was not very clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, you can actually change it without using an extension. I created an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26332) and got the answer that this color is called `editor.rangeHighlightBackground` and you can override it in your User Settings (`settings.json`) by:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.rangeHighlightBackground": "#00AA00"
    }
}
```

To open User Settings just use `Cmd+,` on mac  or `Ctrl+,` on windows

Comment: Seems better than using extentions. Any way one can change transparency level in this setting?

Comment: @Alex this setting accepts color with alpha-channel.

Comment: Whoa! In this case change accepted answer, because obviously your solution is better.

Comment: @Alex I had to wait before SO let me do it :)

Comment: Editor colors in official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors

Answer (score 13):

A wrapup answer:

For VS Code 1.52+
You can use this snippet to customize error colors:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "editorError.background": "#ff80ab66",
     "editorError.foreground": "#d50000",
}
```

Available properties: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 5):

Check if you can apply a different theme with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), considering the new feature:

> ### [Error background colors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/559066a777d1f235bef4e40dab0385cd540ba8b7/release-notes/v1_52.md#error-background-colors)
>
> Theme authors can now leverage new theme colors for errors in the editor.
>
> **Edior errors, warnings, and infos can now be styled** via:
>
> ```
> editorError.background
> editorWarning.background
> editorInfo.background
> ```
>
> [image: Error background colors]

Comment: This is cool, I really want to know what is the exact color and alpha value used in the doc. Designers are much better at picking a desirable color.

Comment: @Sean From the PR (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110112/files), you can see colors in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2b9ae05554e2b3105b22d3cf0452ae3b85f1987b/src/vs/platform/theme/common/colorRegistry.ts#L246-L248