# How to remove red background from ESLint errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I've looked through ESLint's documentation and I can't seem to find the property that's responsible the red background. How can I remove this red background?

I'm using VSCode. Just to clarify, I want to keep the red squiggly lines, but not the red background. It makes it difficult to read my code if everything is lit up red

[image: Big red background that I'd like to remove]

Comment: it's your editor.

Comment: I would worry about removing error itself. By the way, you should use `onClick={(prev) => setPadding(prev + 15)}`

Comment: The issue is, for example, if I haven't finished writing a function yet my entire file will light up red, which makes it very difficult to read my code. I just want the red squiggly lines but not the red background.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `editor.rangeHighlightBackground` for vs code. See this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43896449/12282249

Comment: I added that line into my settings.json and it still seems to have a red background.