# VS Code: Change color of squiggly underline for Lint

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

My configurations currently show the same red squiggly line for Typescript errors and TSLint warnings.

I am using [TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) extension for Visual Studio Code but the configuration I believe is a general VS Code configuration.

This is what it **should** look like:

[image: Image of what it should look like]

I found [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9209) to take it further than just Squiggly lines.

It's not a duplicate of "[How to change error styles in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697223/how-to-change-error-styles-in-vs-code)" because I need to change the color of **Lint**'s warnings only. NOT every error.

Comment: You can't change it for **Lint** only. All errors and warnings have the same style.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a setting to have the tslint extension return warnings (green) instead of errors (red): `"tslint.alwaysShowRuleFailuresAsWarnings": true`

Also, you can change your tslint config to determine which issues are errors, and which are warnings.

Comment: Lint configurations has the option: "defaultSeverity": "warning".
But the configuration you mentioned did the trick :D

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if there's something else you're supposed to set on the tslint config to get it to produce warnings instead. But if tslint is actually producing warnings and vscode shows them as errors, that would be a bug on the tslint extension.

Comment: If you're interested here's my tslint.json and the VS settings are pretty much the default ones.

https://github.com/esantini/React_Example/blob/master/tslint.json

Comment: THANKKKKKK YOU! Needed this so bad! 

Comment: For anyone looking for eslint version that should be: `"eslint.rules.customizations": [ { "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" } ] }` (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint#settings-options). Thank You for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 19):

VSCode v1.17 added the ability to set the color of warnings ("squiggles") and info:

[Modify warning and info squiggles](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_coloring-of-warning-squiggles).

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorWarning.foreground": "#ff0",
  "editorInfo.foreground": "#00f"
}
```

Comment: Well, it won't change styling for **Lint only**. It will change it for all warnings.

Comment: Yes.  A little confusing as to what exactly the OP wanted: "I need to change the color of Lint's warnings only. NOT every error."  So all warnings might be fair game.

Comment: I only have TypeScript errors and Lint warnings, so all warnings would be fair game.
Can't test your solution at the moment but thank you for the contribution :)

Comment: It would be really nice to differentiate by color the different source of errors (eg. ESLint vs. TSLint, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

For eslint I was able to just set specific rules to warning, which I think is a better way to do it rather than trying to set all to one level. The unused vars was the one that really annoyed me, so:

in the `.eslintrc` file...

```
{
    "rules" : {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this. I wish the OP indicated TSLint in the question. I had to add warn to multiple rules to get my "Colors for ESLint only", because marking as errors while I'm coding is just annoying. I do wish somebody had a solution that did the same as the TSLint "defaultSeverity" though. If somebody finds that it would cover all rules and I'd be golden.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix your problem.

Add `"defaultSeverity": "warning"`in  **tslint.json**.

Reference: [Change underline color to avoid confusion with compiler errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/308)

Answer (score 3):

For the ESLint plugin:

```
    "eslint.rules.customizations": [
        { "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" }        
    ]
```

Setting was found in the [GitHub PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/pull/1164#issuecomment-814916237).

Comment: Also described at the [plugin page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

Answer (score 1):

as i was reading through https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15866 I realized my problem was realated to `prettier`. \

just adjust `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'warn',
  },
```

and red underscore becomes yellow underscore

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).