# Change squiggly line color under warnings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

After installing ESLint in VSCode, I'm receiving some warnings like:

> 'variable' is assigned a value but never used

The underline color is red, but how do I change that color? I have tried:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#00FF00",
    "editorError.foreground": "#00FF00",
    "editorWarning.border": "#00FF00",
    "editorError.border": "#00FF00"
}
```

but they change the color of the underlined border, which is not the squiggly one as shown here:

[image]

How do I change that red color into `#00FF00` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code: Change color of squiggly underline for Lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578802/vs-code-change-color-of-squiggly-underline-for-lint)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably want to customize your eslint config to set these as warnings instead of errors. But if you want to change the color of all error squigglies in the app, this works for me:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#00ff00"
}
```

Comment: What on earth... That's exactly what I wrote and now it works. How weird is that? Maybe it's because my HEX colors were capitalized... hmmm.

Comment: You can also do eg `"editorError.background": "#ff0000"` to make them really jump out! I kept missing the sqiggly lines with my ageing eyesight! ;-)

Answer (score 43):

The answers here talk about changing the color for all kind of errors (not just from the eslint).

I'm not sure this is what intended (at least I didn't want it to behave like that).
I wanted to show all JS errors in **red** but all ESLint errors in **orange** (as warnings).

The way to do it is by editing `eslint.rules.customizations` at the settings:

```
  "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    { "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" },
  ]
```

See more info at the [ESLint plugin homepage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

Comment: Excellent! This was the best answer for me... have an upvote!

Comment: Rules that are turned off in the eslint config are not turned into warnings or errors. The customization only applies to lint rules already detected as 'warn' or 'error', which is exactly what you'd want.

Comment: 'Combining both @jurl and Rob's answers here for a complete solution
{
  "eslint.rules.customizations": [{ "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" }],
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#00FF00"
  }
}

Comment: Actually I can do you one better: If you don't want to lose the differentiation between errors and warnings, you can use this:
{ "rule": "*", "severity": "downgrade" }

This will use the warning color for eslint errors and the info color for eslint warnings. :)

Answer (score 15):

VSCode v1.17 added the ability to set the color of warnings ("squiggles") and info:

[Modify warning and info squiggles.](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_coloring-of-warning-squiggles)

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorWarning.foreground": "#ff0",
  "editorInfo.foreground": "#00f"
}
```

[This answer Also added to [squiggles for TSLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578802/vs-code-change-color-of-squiggly-underline-for-lint/46597525#46597525)]

Answer (score 0):

For me after many try to change **"workbench.colorCustomizations"** from VSC settings but not satisified result .
I found out that TsLint Extention i use is (deprecated)
and their is another one from **microsoft** not **egamma**
[image]

but after i install this one every thing back to normal
[image]