# VSCode - gray out unused imports

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VSCode so that it displays unused import as grayed?
I have VSCode 1.21.0, using Typescript 2.7.2

I found and tried several setups but none worked for me. Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539259/how-can-i-show-unused-imports-locals-in-green-warning-in-vscode-rather-than-r) it should have been possible since version 1.19.0

I tried setting tsconfig as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/219) but the only effect was lots of error during compilation.

It seems to be so basic requirement that I would even consider it as default setting. It is definitely possible in other editors (e.g. WebStorm). I love VSCode but I'm really missing this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wait for some time since they have a plan to release this soon.

Checkout this link **[`Suggestion: Show unused imports in VS Code Editor as grayed #8165`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8165)**

Comment: @eXavier The issue is now fixed. You can see how to use it in [Matt Bierener's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401703/2188407)

Comment: Hi, could you help? I've tried all the fixes here, and none work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118036/vscode-is-not-graying-out-unused-variables

Answer (score 11):

For me the problem was that I had turned off `javascript.validate.enable`, so even though the `editor.showUnused` was set to true, it didn't work. So the fix for me was to have both:

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": true,
  "editor.showUnused": true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This feature was added for JavaScript and TypeScript [with VS Code 1.24](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15710)

[image]

VS Code ships with built-in support for fading out unused locals/parameters/imports in JavaScript and TypeScript. You can enable/disable this feature by [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
// For all languages (it is enabled the default)
"editor.showUnused": true

// Or just for a specific language
"[typescript]": {
   "editor.showUnused": true
}
```

Extensions can also add support for other languages.

You can additionally mark unused variables as warnings by setting `noUnusedLocals` and/or `noUnusedParameters` in your `jsconfig` or `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This adds a squiggly and error for unused variables in addition to graying them out:

[image]

Comment: Cool. Just received update 1.24.1. and it finally works!

Comment: Is this functionality available to Language extensions? I would really love to see this implemented into the D Language extension, but I can't find any related symbols in the API for it.

Comment: Yes, see `DiagnosticTag.Unnecessary`. This will grey out the diagnostic's span

Comment: "editor.showUnused" is enabled, but not all unused imports are faded out. VSCode 1.40.2, TypeScript 3.6.3

Comment: They're grayed out in `javascript` files, but by some reason not listed in problems as warnings or anything :\ So it's easy to miss them out

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to select language mode.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Update tslint.json file in project folder with the correct rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    .........
    .........
  }
}
```

Also verify in vscode that:

```
"typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": true
```

Unused imports will be reported as warnings. More information in tslint [documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/).

Comment: Tried that. Now I can see `Warning: The 'no-unused-variable' rule requires type information.` in the output. I found there are few issues with all that in ts-lint 5. I cannot use the workaround in tsconfig as it produces too many errors during production build (most of them are from 3rd party components)

Comment: Yes, this rule requires type information, but works.