# How can i change Error fill color in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Have the problem with VSCode Error fill color.

On the picture, there is a row with a error.

Row have the golden color, that i want to change.
Can't find settings for this parameter.

[image]

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697223/how-to-change-error-styles-in-vs-code - I think in this case you may want to change `editorError.background`.

Comment: how does it look in different themes, the program can control the color to use, if I run a git bash shell in a light theme it looks a bit pastel

Comment: @Caramiriel, Thanks for your answer. I checked it, it's not what I'm looking for.

Changed `editorError.background` on the pink color. It changed color of my error in a row (default - red underline), but not error fill color that you can see on the picture.

Comment: Ah, I just realized its a console window. Then that's not applicable, I agree. That was just for the editor window itself.

Comment: Same problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832689/change-the-highlight-color-text-color-in-vscode-traceback