# Change the highlight-color/text-color in VSCode traceback

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode a highlight of the error-lines has been introduced (which I find fantastic!).

The issue is, that the highlight color is yellow and the text white, thuse I barely read the lines, see below
[image]

Is there a way to change either the highlight color/the text in the highlighted box or the "intensity" of the yellow i.e make it more transparent?

Comment: You can find an answer for this at this stack overflow comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60709686

Comment: or the Theme does not have these colors defined and it uses the default colors

Comment: I can't see any difference when using the suggested answer.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use the field `terminal.ansiYellow` in `settings.json` to change the highlight color, e.g.,

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
    "terminal.ansiYellow": "#1E1E1E",
}
```